# Loading /register (laravel auth out-of-box) on a modal form submit issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, authentication, modal-dialog

I'm using laravel 5.2 and it's own auth api, Let's go step by step. I'm making a website which I want to have the sign up form inside a modal so, I use jquery to load the route /register on my modal when somebody click sign up, Form is load and everything is great but when I submit this form I got redirect 302 to index. It's not a token trouble because I'm loading the form with ajax and it's creating the right token input. Any idea why laravel is having this behaviour? thanks.

Comment: could you post how you render your modal form? also, `routes.php` and controller code if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tezla . routes.php [link](http://pastie.org/10672474) AuthController.php [link](http://pastie.org/10672475).

Comment: hmm, your `route.php` seems ok. just to be sure, you're using `{{ url('/register') }}` right? not plain url with slash? also [http 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) shows that it's not token input. laravel by default, after user registration/login will redirect to `/` (home), while it can be changed in `AuthController.php` in line 31.